# comparing caret models with mean or median?

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, caret

I am using `caret` to evaluate the classification performance of several models on a small dataset (190 obs) with two classes and just a handful of features.

When I inspect the `train()` object for one of the models, I get what looks to be the mean metric values (ROC, Sens, and Spec).

```
Resampling: Cross-Validated (10 fold, repeated 5 times) 
Summary of sample sizes: 171, 171, 171, 171, 171, 171, ... 
Resampling results across tuning parameters:

  nIter  method         ROC        Sens       Spec
   50    Adaboost.M1    0.8866667  0.9866667  0.58
   50    Real adaboost  0.5566667  0.9844444  0.50
  100    Adaboost.M1    0.8844444  0.9877778  0.58
  100    Real adaboost  0.5738889  0.9833333  0.52
  150    Adaboost.M1    0.8800000  0.9877778  0.60
  150    Real adaboost  0.5994444  0.9833333  0.52
```

When I use the `resamples()` function and put all of the models in a list, I get the means again, but also the median values. (other model results omitted for clarity)

```
Models: RF, GBM, SVM, ADABOOST, C5, NB 
Number of resamples: 50 

ROC 
            Min. 1st Qu. Median   Mean 3rd Qu. Max. NA's
ADABOOST 0.25000  0.8958 0.9444 0.8867       1    1    0

Sens 
           Min. 1st Qu. Median   Mean 3rd Qu.   Max. NA's
ADABOOST 0.8889  1.0000 1.0000 0.9867  1.0000 1.0000    0

Spec 
         Min. 1st Qu. Median Mean 3rd Qu. Max. NA's
ADABOOST    0       0      1 0.58       1    1    0
```

The `bwplot()` function appears to display the median values as the point estimates.

[image]

It seems to me like the `train()` output wants me to evaluate the models based on the means. `bwplot()` focuses on the median. My first thought was that the median would be a better metric with such spread.

Which would you use, and why?

Comment: And I should say that using/reporting both is probably a good strategy, but I'm interested in knowing which one to lean on for decision-making.

Comment: I tend to like medians slightly more than means, but I'm having trouble articulating why.

Comment: Comments: 1. With 190 obs. only when you do 10-fold cross validation you end up with very unstable estimates. I would suggested bootstrapping; if you are partial to $k$-fold validation, increasing the number of repeats by *a lot*. 2. Having said that, just look at the KDE of your performance metrics. Does it make sense to use a central tendency? Specificity for example hints to strong bimodality, ie. both the mean and the median might be useless. Plot the KDEs and re-assess your findings. I would use neither statistic before knowing a bit more about the distribution of what they measure.

Comment: @usεr11852 totally fair comment with respect to this particular case. Thanks for that observation. In the more general case, however, why is the convention (maybe too strong a word) to evaluate with means over medians?

Comment: Well... it says on the tin: "*expected value*" :D. (Plus order statistics are much harder to prove results for than standard marginalisation tasks.)

Answer (score 1):

I would look at the actual distributions and evaluate which measure better describes the distributions. It could very well be that the correct answer is 'neither'.

Comment: Can you expand on this to give the OP more help? How do we tell which best describes? Under what circumstances would neither be the answer?

Answer (score 0):

I would say it depends on what you are trying to achieve and the distribution of the metrics themselves. Means and medians can both hide information that can be very useful for some metrics.

For example in regression it's very common to look at [residual plots](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat501/node/279) to evaluate the goodness of fit. Looking at just the mean or median error would not be very helpful here since the aggregation would hide the useful information (for example if the errors are heteroscedastic)

I would actually worry more about the metrics that you choose to report. In a choice between an median absolute and a mean (squared) error, are you able to motivate your choice of metric?

If your data has many outliers or the dependent is power-law distributed for example, a median absolute error will be more robust compared to the mean.

Out of the outputs you have listed I'd say the `bwplot()` is the most useful one as it conveys the most information, for example the extreme variance for some of the models for the Sensitivity (?) metric. In cases where it's possible to have a visual inspection of the models like this there is not reason to "hide" information using a mean or median metric, box plots are much better.